# Cycles. Image sequence used as texture renders pink

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I add to texture as image sequence on plane I set up first and end frame. Auto refresh and cyclic activated.It works well in rendered mode but texture goes pink when I render it.It seems like texture is missing.

Blender v275
OS Windows 8.1 64 bit
Cycles render

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually i did it again and it's works fine. I don't know what was the problem.. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Usually when blender renders something in bright pink / fuschia , its the indication that the link to the image is broken. Meaning the image texture file or sequence file may have been moved from their original folder or moved to another drive of your computer. Renaming of texture files also causes links to be broken.

If you did not move those files, it can be an indication that your harddisk or operating system are having trouble locating those files. Check to see if it's also an underlying hardware issue.